# Criterion for a map to be homotopy equivalence in terms of its mapping cylinder

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I am trying to prove that a map $f: X \to Y $ is a homotopy equivalence iff $j : X \to Z(f)$ is a deformation retract where $Z(f)$ is the mapping cylinder and $X \to Z(f) \to Y$ is the decomposition $f=qj$ into a homotopy equivalence $q$ and a cofibration $j$. 
I am able to prove that $f$ has a left homotopy inverse iff $j $ has a retraction. But able to proceed further. Any help would be very much appreciated. 
P.S. I encountered this problem while learning Algebraic Topology from Tammy Tom Dieck's book. This is problem 5.3.1 on p 113 there.

Comment: This follows from the fact that $j$ is a homotopy equivalence if $f$ and $q$, and that a homotopy equivalence which is at the same time a cofibration is the inclusion of a deformation retract.

Comment: @StefanHamcke Thank you so much. Actually I am a beginner and could not see this myself even after long struggling. 
By the way, if I am not mistaken, what you said seems to me true slightly more generally. Any inclusion (not necessarily a cofibration) which is a homotopy equivalence is a retract. Am I right ? Thanks